# Confusion Regarding the Elementary Complex Function $z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm taking an introduction to complex variables course, and I've run into a roadblock in my understanding of the material. It may seem trivial, but I'm having trouble understanding, the function $w = z^2$. I'm basically confused about this whole page of notes that I wrote down (along with what the "slit plane" is; I have no idea what this is). The way that my professor dealt with it in notes made it seem like $w$ was a function of $z$, but it should be the other way around, I guess. If anyone can help explain (or summarise as much as they can from my notes), I would appreciate it. I guess to be more specific, I'm confused with the mapping: why the negative real axis isn't included. The images for what I'm talking about are links. Thanks. 
[Notes Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ARFe.jpg)
[Notes Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwDWg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are right that there is no difficulty defining the function $z\mapsto z^2$. I think your notes are concerned with the inverse of this function "$w\mapsto\sqrt{w}$".

Recall that this is already an issue when $w$ is a positive real number; the equation $z^2=w$ has two solutions, and by convention $\sqrt{w}$ denotes the positive root.

We have the same problem for complex numbers but no notion of "positive". We can define $\sqrt{w}$ to be the root with positive real part. This works everywhere except the negative real line. If $w=-1$ then the two roots are $\pm i$, and neither has positive real part. Even if we make some arbitrary choice (eg $\sqrt{-r}=i\sqrt{r}$ for $r>0$ real), the function will have a discontinuity, since $\sqrt{-1+i\epsilon}\approx i$ but $\sqrt{-1-i\epsilon}\approx -i$ where $\epsilon$ is a small positive real number.